# Problems installing Libre Office 4.1 - tar.gz

Tags: libreoffice, software-installation

I've downloaded Libre Office 4.1 for my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, then opened the tar.gx file and clicked on install and then get this:

```
There was a problem opening the file /home/fmfalcao/.cache/.f…4.2_Linux_x86_rpm/install
```

Any reason why?

I've just installed the chrome browser without difficulty and and older version of Libre Office is already on my machine- I just wanted the newer package.

Comment: First `untar` the file to a folder then run the installation file from there.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install an rpm package. R(edhat) P(ackage) M(anagement) is designed for Red Hat and its derivatives. It is an entirely different scheme from Ubuntu, based on Debian's .deb method. I suggest you go back and select the Linux - deb (x86_64), (assuming you have a 64-bit system) version 4.1.4 version and try again.

You also need to uninstall the current libreoffice install in your system.

Another option that doesn't require uninstall libreoffice is, on your own risk, adding the [LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa)